# Property file not found in JAR file

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I have a project which has Main method to invoke the application. Which is bundled in a JAR file.

I am trying to invoke the application using following line:

```
java -jar sample.jar -sample 123
```

This sample.jar bundled with config/config.properties in it.

I have following line of code to read the property file from the JAR.

```
InputStream inputStream =
    this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config/config.properties");
```

OR

```
InputStream inputStream = 
    this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/config/config.properties");
```

This code is not able to find property file from the JAR file, While this property file is already exist in the JAR.

Does any one know the solution on this  ?

Comment: Please show the result of `jar tvf sample.jar`

Comment: 750 Thu Jan 30 15:17:58 PST 2014 config/config.properties

Comment: Can you post a short but complete example demonstrating the problem? It looks like it should work... (without the leading slash, given that you're loading it from the classloader).

Comment: JAR has a Main class META-INF/MANIFEST.MF has this value in it.      Main-Class: com.Main

Answer (score 1):

When i moved config.properties out from the config Folder, it's working fine...

I am not sure why that's the case. But if i use following line of code it's working now..

ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream inputStream = loader.getResourceAsStream("config.properties");